# R: Download from Web Browser - "tell Explorer to download the pdf I'm viewing"

Tags: r, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf, download

I pull up the pdf/html file of interest via:

```
myURL <- www.thingiwant.com/doc.pdf
browseURL(myURL)
```

And now I'd like to save the pdf my browser is viewing via R-code

```
?
```

For a number of security etc. reasons I cannot directly access the documents via R so things like download.file() are not an option for me. This approach is my next best idea.

Comment: Have you looked at the RSelenium package?

Comment: And just so I have it clear you can't use `download.file` but you can save the file from a web browser?

Comment: Yes that it is correct, I can get the files in-browser but not via download.file - I can't pass my security credentials through download.file so when I try using it I just get the log-on page

Comment: There is probably a solution using RCurl.  But it probably is easiest to use RSelenium if you can get it installed.